# Azure DevOps does not allow to add xlsm files as link in wiki

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

I'm trying to add an xlsm file to one of the markdown files in my repository, and that repository is published as wiki. What I want to do is that I want to have the xlsm file to be downloadable from the markdown file when click on it. This works perfectly fine for file formats such as docx, pdf and xlsx, but when I add an xlsm file as a link, it gets blocked. The link is highlighted as red and when I click on it, it goes to a not-found page instead of downloading it.

[image]

[image]

It looks like this is implemented by Microsoft as a sort of a security precaution for macro-enabled excel files, but is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

A rather poor workaround is to name your files with another, fictitious file extension, e.g. `MyFile.xlsm.xlsx` or `MyFile.xlsm.txt`. Then you can provide instructions to your users to download/save them with the fictitious extension removed, e.g. `MyFile.xlsm`. From a security perspective, this is not an advisable practice.

I cannot find official documentation stating which files are or are not supported. However, it's reasonable to assume you are correct. The `.xlsm` files are likely blocked for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of the file formats supported in Azure Wiki's:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#attachments

Adding `.txt` extension works, but bad thing is that when the user saves the file it get's the name `item.txt`.